# Keep EntityObject from changing into Added state (Entity Framework)

Tags: entity-framework, state

Stupid question maybe, yet still.

```
public class Foo : EntityObject 
{
    public Bar Bar { get; set; } // navigation property
}
public class Bar : EntityObject
{
    // whatever
}

// code
var myFoo = Foo.Create(); // detached state after this line
var myBar = LoadMyBarFromDatabase(); // Bar comes from DB
myFoo.Bar = myBar; // myFoo.EntityState changes to 'Added'
```

I do not need `myFoo` to be added to the database. It must remain detached. I just need it as a fake container of `Bar` for some time. Nothing else.

Thoughts?

(At the moment I only have a thought to add a new interface `IFoo` and implement it in `FakeFoo` class, which is not an `EntityObject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, seems like there is no good solid way to do this. I ended up overriding the `SaveChanges` method in context and filtering out the trash objects I created. Did not really find anything else since as soon as you add the object to some relationship it is added to the context with the `Added` state.